# How can I fix the Axios get request and the React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, axios

### **Details about my goal:**

> *I want to create a React App with Material UI that detects gender on the basis of your name.*

### **Summary of the problem:**

- I am not getting back the result for the name that is entered into the input field
- Expected Result:

  - `{name: "Alice" gender: "female", probability: 0.83, count: 3387}`
- Actual Result:

  - `null`
  - `undefined`
  - `{data: "Data was undefined"}`

### **Useful resources for this issue:**

- This is the link to the CodeSandBox for this problem: [click here --see what I have tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/gender-detector-sglem?file=/src/components/Container.jsx)
- Gender.io API link (I used this API to detect gender): [click here](https://genderize.io/)
- Material UI for React: [click here](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)

Comment: Can anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is a little over-engineered, and doesn't properly handle the asynchronous nature of the request.

What I typically do is return the fetch or axios object so that the calling component can wait for the response and handle it when it's ready.

[Forked example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gender-detector-forked-86eqr?file=/src/components/Container.jsx)

As you can see, I've removed a couple of pieces from your Container.jsx component (which might need a different name fwiw).

Instead of setting a flag for the form being ready to submit, I just have the button directly calling the `fetchNameData` function.

The `checkGender` function from your utilities function now directly returns the axios object, which is a promise. The `fetchNameData` function is async so it can wait for the results from this promise.

Comment: Not working properly. Try with multiple inputs. You will find the issue.

Comment: Your example only has a single input. If you mean sequentially, it works fine. You'll need to be more specific with what you're expecting.

Comment: When I give the 1st input: the result is null ------- 
When I give the 2nd input: the result is correct for the 2nd input ------- 
When I give the 3rd input: the result is correct for the 2nd input ------- 
When I give the 4th input: the result is correct for the 3rd input -------

Comment: How can I fix this problem

Comment: Somehow the previous input remains preserved.

Comment: I have changed the console.log(resp.data) to console.log(response).

Comment: Hence I found that there is some problem with the state of the response object.

Comment: Are you talking about your codesandbox, or the corrected fork of it I shared in my answer? You were not properly handling async code, i.e. you were updating your display before the result was back from the API. So yes, it would start null and then be one submission behind. But look at my fork and you'll see that, since we now wait for the response, they line up correctly.

Comment: Open this link to the SandBox: [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gender-detector-v-2-xdyeu?file=/src/components/Container.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, if the name starts with a lowercase, it will throw an error, so what you can do is capitalize the first letter of the user input
[image]

Comment: the user has to click many times on the detect button to get the need data. Before that, responses like 'null' and 'undefined' are coming.

Comment: Oh well, I clicked once and got the data.